# iOS prevent rotations until after animation completes

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, locking, screen-rotation

I'm creating an iOS app and in one method I have a for loop that does a series of animations that last around 2 seconds.

My problem is that if the user rotates the device while the animations are still in progress, it messes up the formatting for the new orientation (everything works just the way it should if the rotation happens *after* the animation is complete).

So I was wondering if there is a way to delay rotations

Comment: Are you using `UIView` animation blocks?

Comment: Yes, I am using animation blocks

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `BOOL` instance variable that you update based on whether your animation is complete or not. Then override the `shouldAutorotate` method and return that `BOOL`. Might look something like this:

```
@implementation YourViewController {
    BOOL _shouldAutoRotate;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    [super shouldAutorotate];
    return _shouldAutoRotate;
}

-(void)yourAnimationMethod {

    _shouldAutoRotate = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        //your animations
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished) {
            _shouldAutoRotate = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```